# Turbo assembler cs section explain

Tags: assembly, tasm

I'm trying to trace the program I've searched using turbo assembler but im stocked with this values:

```
cs:0006->8ED8           mov ds,ax
cs:0392->66B800060000   mov eax,00000600
cs:039A->66B900000000   mov ecx,00000000
```

can someone help me explain this? Especially the numbers showed in cs part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"cs" refers to the current code segment, the number after it refers to the offset within the segment. The number after the arrow is the opcode of the instruction.

```
cs:0006->8ED8           mov ds,ax
 ^   ^     ^
 |   |     |
 |   |     +-- Opcode of the "mov ds,ax" instruction
 |   |
 |   +-- Offset of the instruction within the code segment (6 bytes)
 |
 +-- Current code segment, see contents of your CS register
```

See also [X86 Memory Segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) for more details.

For a list of x86 opcodes, see http://ref.x86asm.net/

Comment: i still can't get it.Can you explain further?

Comment: You need to be more specific :) What exactly is your question?

Comment: ok i see, but what about that offset?i mean if it is "39A" does it mean it's 922 bytes? by the way, what is opcode?

Comment: Yes, it is 922 bytes. In X86 real mode, a physical (20 bit) address is built from two 16 bit registers - a segment register and an offset (PC, the program counter, in case of CS). The segment is shifted 4 bits to left and the offset added to obtain the physical address. `opcode`  is the binary representation of a CPU instruction. In the sample above, `8E` is the `MOV` instruction and `D8` encodes the operands (`ds,ax`).

Comment: im little bit confused about the offset but anyway il work on that.If the 8E is the mov instruction then why does in the next line it is not 8E (668B8006000)?

Comment: Its a different `mov` - it uses a different address mode (immediate, not register) and it is also a 32 bit instruction (uses extended (32 bit) AX register). `66` is the "operand override prefix" to mark the operand as 32 bit, `B8` is then the actual opcode for moving an immediate value to the (E)AX register